# How to enable the button when the user selects the value in the select box In Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce app and I am showing products with the size but the problem is that, I want to restrict user to select the product size and then move the product to the cart but I am not able to do that.

This is my **productdetails.html**:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Products</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<ion-row align-items-center class="mynewr11">
 <ion-col *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">
  <img class="myimg11" src="{{product.image}}" />
  <p>{{ product.product_name }}</p>

<ion-col *ngIf="nosize" style="padding: 0px;">
<ion-select placeholder="Select Size" [(ngModel)]="product.SelectedSize">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let psize of product.product_size" value="{{psize.size}}">{{psize.size}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-col>

  <button [disabled]="!isenabled" class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button small>
    Add to Cart
  </button>

</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

In the **productdetails.ts**:

```
isenabled: boolean = false;
```

In this html, I am showing the product size and the AddToCart button. I want the user to select the size first and then move the product to the cart. I have disabled the button initially and it will enable when the user selects the size but the problem is that I am not able to apply the select value logic. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could listen to the change event on the ion-select and if the selected value is accepted you change the isenabled value:

```js
valueChanged(event) {
  isenabled = true;
}
```

```html
<ion-select (ionChange)="valueChanged($event)">
```

Another alternative is to bind [enabled] to the value of selectedSize:

```html
<button [disabled]="!product.SelectedSize" class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button small>
    Add to Cart
  </button>
```

Comment: [disabled]="!product.SelectedSize", In this, I am not showing the size in some of the products. So, this wont work for all the products.

Comment: valueChanged(event) {
  isenabled = true;
}. In this, when I clcik the size of one product, all products addtocart button is enabled. So, can you please help me in this.

Comment: Ok, this wasn't clear.
You must think of some extra logic that fits your requirements.

In the case of the [disabled] solution, I asume that when you're not showing the size, then it is not required to add the product to the chart. So if you are not showing the size, enable the button, if you are showing the size, enable the button when there is a selected size.

In the case of the valueChanged solution, you shouldn't have only one isenabled boolean but an array of booleans that has the same length as your products, an access it according to it's index.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the solution but If there are 4 products on the page and with different sizes and addtocart button and when the user selects the one product size, it will only enable that product addtocart button and in my case it is enabling all addtocart button.

Comment: Yes, that's why isenabled should be an array of booleans. One for each product.
You can access the a specific boolean with the product index. You can get the index like this:
<ion-col *ngFor="let i = index; let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">